# xmpp IQ XML parsing in iOS

Tags: ios, xml, xmppframework

I received the following XML IQ and want to parse it in iOS. Please help!

```
     <iq type="result">
        <stories xmlns="success">

            <storyid>1</storyid>
            <title>THE TITLE</title>
            <picture>BASE64EncodedStringOfImage</picture>

            <storyid>2</storyid>
            <title>Love At First Site</title>
            <picture>BASE64EncodedStringOfImage</picture>

        </stories>
     </iq>
```

I tried the below code but it isn't working. It gets the values in `successStoryArray` but nothing afterwards. Please help!

```
    NSXMLElement *stories = [iq elementForName:@"stories"];
    NSArray *successStoryArray = [stories elementsForName:@"storyid"];
    NSLog(@"successStoryArray: %@", successStoryArray);
    for (NSXMLElement *i in successStoryArray)
    {
        NSXMLElement *title = [i elementForName:@"title"];
        NSString *sTitle = [title stringValue];
        NSLog(@"sTitle: %@", sTitle);
        NSXMLElement *picture = [i elementForName:@"picture"];
        NSString *sPicture = [picture stringValue];
        NSLog(@"sPicture: %@", sPicture);

    }
```

Comment: what have u tried?? try out this if you simply dont know where to start http://techglimpses.blogspot.in/2013/03/xml-parsing-in-ios-sample-code.html

Comment: @Agent I have added above what I have tried.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are iterating over the wrong elements. `NSArray *successStoryArray = [stories elementsForName:@"storyid"];` will get two elements: storyid with value=1 and storyid with value=2.
Then you iterate over those elements and trying to extract title and picture, but title and picture are not child elements of . Title and picture are at the same level as storyid, they are children of .

There are two ways to fix it:

**Extract 3 arrays**, each containing the values for storyid, title and picture

```
NSArray *successStoryArray = [stories elementsForName:@"storyid"];
NSArray *titleArray = [stories elementsForName:@"title"];
NSArray *pictureArray = [stories elementsForName:@"picture"];
```

Then you can iterate them in order and items will match

**Even better** in my opinion, change the structure of the XML by wrapping each story in a  element, like this:

```
     <iq type="result">
        <stories xmlns="success">
          <story>
            <storyid>1</storyid>
            <title>THE TITLE</title>
            <picture>BASE64EncodedStringOfImage</picture>
          </story>
          <story>
            <storyid>2</storyid>
            <title>Love At First Site</title>
            <picture>BASE64EncodedStringOfImage</picture>
          </story>
        </stories>
     </iq>
```

Then you can do:

```
    NSXMLElement *stories = [iq elementForName:@"stories"];
    NSArray *successStoryArray = [stories elementsForName:@"story"];
    NSLog(@"successStoryArray: %@", successStoryArray);
    for (NSXMLElement *i in successStoryArray)
    {
        NSXMLElement *storyId = [i elementForName:@"storyId"];
        NSString *sId = [storyId stringValue];
        NSLog(@"sId: %@", sId);
        NSXMLElement *title = [i elementForName:@"title"];
        NSString *sTitle = [title stringValue];
        NSLog(@"sTitle: %@", sTitle);
        NSXMLElement *picture = [i elementForName:@"picture"];
        NSString *sPicture = [picture stringValue];
        NSLog(@"sPicture: %@", sPicture);

    }
```